# Can an articulation point have all edges as non-bridge?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

The two endpoints of a bridge are articulation vertices unless they have a degree of 1. Will these articulation vertices form the complete set of articulation points of an undirected graph ?

Specifically, can there exist an articulation point such that every edge connecting it is not a bridge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a graph on vertices $a,b,c,d,e$, where $a,b,c$ form a triangle, and $a,d,e$ also form a triangle.
[image]

Then $a$ is an articulation point since removing it will disconnect the component $b,c$ from $d,e$. However, none of the edges incident to $a$ are bridges since they all lie on a cycle.

So you are correct, an articulation point can have no bridges incident to it.

Answer (score -1):

Good question. The definition of bridge corresponds to an edge that binds two strongly connected components together. If we remove all bridges, we have all strongly connected components. An articulation point is itself an strongly connected component. Therefore, all edges connected to articulation points are bridges.

Comment: What about the graph on vertices $a,b,c,d$ where vertices $a,b,c$ form a triangle, and $\{a,d\}$ is an edge. Then $a$ is an articulation point since removing it disconnects the graph, but $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ are not bridges, only $\{a,d\}$ is a bridge.

Comment: You are right. Here is your cookie.